# phpseclib ssh2 enable tty

Tags: php, linux, phpseclib

my ssh script:

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
set_include_path(getcwd());



$ssh_host = "myserver.com";
if($ssh_host != null){
    $ssh_user = globals::$ssh_logins[$ssh_host];
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($ssh_host);
    //$ssh->enablePTY();
    if (!$ssh->login($ssh_user['username'], $ssh_user['password'])) {
        echo $ssh->isConnected() ? 'bad username or password' : 'unable to establish connection';
    }
    echo $ssh->exec('sudo bash /myscript.sh');
}else{
    echo "no host: " . $ssh_host;
}
```

when calling:

```
echo $ssh->exec('sudo bash /myscript.sh');
```

i get the output:

```
stdin: is not a tty
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

**how do i enable tty on phpseclib?**
Sudo is necessary also it is important to retrieve the output. my script returns multiple lines.

- Centos 7
- PHP 7

interesting link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136676/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo-when-using-sudo-in-a-remote-scrip?newreg=f31852b195804fd1b988aeb0a9ce59d9

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with your `$ssh->enablePTY()` but once you do that you'll need to do `$ssh->read()`. Without a PTY `$ssh->exec()` will return the commands output. If you do `$ssh->enablePTY()` you'll need to do `$ssh->read()` to get output.

The reason for this is that with a PTY data can be sent to and from the shell whereas it can't without a PTY. Without a PTY the output you get is the output you get and no input can change that because you can't send input. With a PTY input can change the output.

Also relevant, phpseclib's docs talk about doing `sudo` with it. From http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#sudo :

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
}
```

If your account doesn't have a password I guess it doesn't matter but if you do have a password then you'll need to do something like the above.